# Are there satellites in LEO that can be seen by naked eyes in the daytime?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, visual-signature

Are there any satellites in LEO that we can see with naked eyes in the daytime, or any *special situations* where they might become visible during the day?

If there is, how high, and at what orientation would those orbits be?

If not, how high can we see in the daylight?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a really good question! While usually not, there are many interesting exceptions, so I expect there will be more than one answer.

Comment: 'how high can we see in the daylight' - we sometimes see the moon, so at least 300.000km , and Halleys Comet (millions of km) was also visible during daytime... as were some supernovas (trillions of km) - what is it you are actually interested in - please refine your question.

Comment: @bukwyrm Also, we can see the **sun**.

Comment: @gerrit i did indeed miss that object - though it is even more special: we can _only_ see it in daylight :-)

Comment: I mean how height for the artificial object (especially satellties) in the sky can be seen by us in the daytime. As gerrit said, we can see the sun.

Comment: Assuming very clear air, you can just look at something of the same relative brigthness (depending on sun angle, some aircraft or satellites will reflect sunlight to you, and be quite bright relative to the sky, which can be quite dark if there is no dust and condenstation (clouds) in the air) at a known distance, and then extrapolate. If you you just so see a black insect of 1mm at one meter against the sky, you might see an insect of similar brightness ten times as big at ten times the distance, etc. Dust and condensation will skew that. Note that, i.e. military drones are sky-camo-painted

Comment: Also, is this about any man made objects, so also including those that produce light of their own (in contrast to i.e. balloons that are simply illuminated by the sun, and even with an albedo of 1 will never get brighter than a certain value)? Please include all your clarifications from the comments in the question, too.

Comment: our ability to see something does not depend on distance, it depends on light coming from the object,  reaching our eyes and our ability to recognize the said object. it helps if the light intensity or color from the object is not similar to the background.

Answer (score 13):

While @gerrit [may very much doubt it](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30530/12102) the periodic reflections from the original Iridium satellites, known as [Iridium flares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_flare#Iridium_flares) can be as bright as magnitude -8 and certainly can be as bright as Venus more frequently than that.

Venus can be seen in the daytime if you know where to look of course.

- EarthSky.org [Top 10 space objects to see during the day](http://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/10-surprising-things-to-see-in-the-daytime-sky) worth a read!
- Space.com [Rare Sight: See Venus During the Day (Photo)](https://www.space.com/24667-rare-venus-daytime-sky-views.html)

And of course if a satellite's orbit goes low enough to begin reentry, it will generate a fireball which could potentially be viewable in the day, if it was large (e.g. Skylab, ISS, Tiangong-2, Mir...) Of course then it will cease to be a satellite, and cease to be in orbit.

It's hard to state a particular height when an object will be visible during the day. A 747 jumbo jet at 40,000 feet (about 12 km) something *definitely not in orbit* is already difficult if not impossible to spot unless it is making condensation trails or it has some peculiar reflection.

An extremely tiny dot of light on a black background is visible even if unresolved, but an unresolved dot of black on a bright background is just not detectable with human vision. This is a combination of the nonlinear way the human eye and visual system works, and shot noise (or whatever the biological equivalent is), but that's a different question.

Comment: HhHh, that's a abnormal case for observing the LEO man-made objects:-) Is there any guess for the height, up to which mankind can see a moving object  in the very clear sky with naked eyes? I think Gerrit provided a good way to get the height for seeing.

Comment: @alex its possible more answers will show up. I've added some more about height. Really it's not a question of height though, it's a question of brightness and resolution.

Comment: @alex it entirely depends on the size of the object.

Comment: It's probably both. The brighter it is, the easier it is to see. The closer it is, the easier it is to see.

Comment: @MooingDuck that's a good point! And color, and texture and orientation and shape and...

Answer (score 3):

I've been part of stratospheric balloon launches.  Those balloons go up to 30 km and inflate to huge spheres up there with dozens of metre in diameter.  They are barely visible with the naked eye, you won't see them if not looking very carefully in the right direction.

Satellites are much (factor 10 in each dimension) smaller and much (factor 20) higher up.  They don't normally reflect enough sunlight to be visible against the blue background sky.  *Maybe*  you could see one flashing if specular reflection reflected a sunray straight to the observer, but I very much doubt it.

Comment: Thanks. that's one of the real observations. Could you give a guess of the height of the situation when the balloons are barely visible with your naked eyes?